# PlUpload cancel file upload which is in progress

Tags: plupload

I am working with PlUpload and cancel upload works fine when I select one file. But when I choose multiple files and want to cancel some of the files, it does not work and code to cancel works for the last cancel button. Here is the code I am using. Please suggest what I am doing wrong and why it is binding to last cancel button created when I select multiple files.

```js
uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
  plupload.each(files, function(file) {
    up.settings.multipart_params = {
      WorkflowId: upload.attr("id"),
    };

    document.getElementById("spn_" + browseButtonId).innerHTML += "<div id='" + file.id + "'>" + "<a href='javascript:void(0)' id='cancel" + file.id + "'>cancel</a><i></i></div>";

    (function() {
      var ind = file.id;
      $("#cancel" + ind).click(function() {
        if (file.status == plupload.UPLOADING) {
          uploader.stop();
          uploader.removeFile(file);
          $(this).unbind().remove();
        }
      });
    })();



  });
  uploader.start();
});
```

Comment: It works fine when I select only one file.

Comment: seems like a scope issue. You should try declaring `var thisfile = file;` at the same level of the ind variable, and use `thisfile` in your cancel click handler, instead of `file` (or try to just pass file as parameter of your immediate function)

Comment: I tried, but no luck.. :(